# IF Statement - 2 conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if statement which is contingent on 2 conditions.

I have tried:

```
<?php if($nominated=='yes' || $approved=='no'): ?>
```

But this doesn't work as it displays results that have either, ie, all results which are nominated and all results which are not approved.

This is incorrect.

for example. there are 10 rows in total. 4 are nominated, 1 of those is approved.
Using the above code pulls all 4, since the first criteria `$nominated=='yes'` is met.
When I'm trying to pull only 1 row, the row which is nominated AND not approved.

Comment: What if you change `||` to `&&`?

Comment: My mom sent me to the corner store to bring milk, and if they have eggs, bring six. So I brought her six bottles of milk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the correct way to do what you are wanting to do:

```
if($nominated=='yes' && $approved=='no')
```

`||` = OR - must satisfy only 1 condition to be true

`&&` = AND - both conditions must be satisfied in order to be true

If you would like to learn more about binary logical operators you can check this manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: If you go further with PHP, you'll learn that PHP evaluates if operations from left to right; if connected through OR, and the first one fails, it won't check the next conditions. Means, in high performance applications you'll always put the most expensive argument to the right and the cheapest to the left.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that, must have forgot the refresh the page when I tested it.